# Create Backbutton programmatically without navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation, uistoryboard, back

In my iPhone App, I have 2 Storyboard, where I switch from `Main.storyboard` to `Camera.storyboard` and back. When I am on the Camera.storyboard I want to have the Backbutton functionality and look like the backbutton of the navigation conroller.

**How do I do this best, without navigation controller?**  Is it possible to clone the navigationbar and backbutton somehow, which I then can connect with my back function?

---

### Update

Had a missunderstanding in my thinking and now a solution **with NavigationController**. I  embeded the `CameraViewController` in a `NavigationController` with IB in the `Camera.storyboard` and added the following code in the `CameraViewController`:

```c
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    }
    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(back)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = cancelButtonItem;
}
```

I did use a cancel button instead a back button as, I did not find the back button and more important, the cancel was logical more correct in this situation.

---

Currently I switch to the Camera.storyboard with this code:

#### ViewController on Main.storyboard

```c
#pragma mark - Segue to CameraView
-(void)toCameraView:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Camera" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *cameraViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    cameraViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:cameraViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

and Back with:

#### CameraViewController on Camera.storyboard

```c
- (IBAction)upload:(id)sender {
    [[WebApi sharedInstance] uploadImage:self.imageView.image];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Why not Navigation controller?

Comment: Use the custom UIBarButton item.

Comment: @Retro if this works. I always thought you need (in IB) to embed the ViewControllers in the NavigationbarController. And than here I have the problem that I have 2 storyboard, and cannot embed... but as I write these lines, I could add the NavigationbarController programatically.... But can I pop from the RootViewController in the NavigationbarController? I my thinking I am already on the bottom of the stack of Views, pop would not be correct...

Comment: @Pavan see comment above

Comment: I think you put your main controller as root and show and hide your camare strorybord will do the trick